# C++ standard way for member aliases without requiring parenthesis or references?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a class, perhaps, a templated fixed-size vector:

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
struct VectorN
{
    T values[N];
}
```

Also, let's make it clear from the start: no #define allowed. I want to make values accessible by x, y, z, w, whatever, names. One of the ways (the "member function" way) is:

```
T& x()
{
    assert(N >= 1);
    return values[0];
}

T& y()
{
   assert(N >= 2);
   return values[1];
}
/* etc */
```

It works, it's efficient and right, but it's ugly, since it requires you to use it like this:

```
//reference alias way
VectorN<4,double> v;
v.x() = 4.4;
v.y() = 12.32;
```

Removing the parenthesis causes "function as a left operand" error. As far as I've heard, making a union with anonymous stucts is not standard. Compiler can padding in between members thus ruining everything. Also, I have no idea how to make it work with variable (yet known at compile time) sizes and it seems dangerous anyway:

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
struct VectorN
{
    union
    {
        T values[N];
        struct
        {
            T x,y,z,w;
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to keep references to original values as variables in the struct:

```
template <size_t N, typename T>
struct VectorN
{
    T values[N];

    T& x, y, z, w;
}
```

But it ballons the size of our vector struct and another problem rises: what if vector's size is not 4? Then one of the references will have to be empty, which is possible, but it is kinda cancer and awful. Using pointers instead is useless - it's ugly, error prone, the function way is much better.

So the question is, how to make aliases to member variables, so they would be able to be used seamlessly, just like native struct, something like this:

```
VectorN<3,int> z;
z.x = 0;
z.y = 1;
z.z = 2;
z.w = 3; //fails cause assertion
```

Is it even possible to make in a portable way?

Comment: *"It works, it's efficient and right, but it's ugly"*. That ugliness is really subjective. Getters use `()`.

Comment: There is still specialization for each case with `N <= 4` but you drop the array and have to provide `operator []` and special iterator.

Comment: The union is non-standard, but you can add `static_assert`s to make sure it's valid that will trigger at compile-time, and tests to be extra safe. Seems to be good enough for quite a lot of people who want this feature.

Comment: @super: the union is also UB if you read non-active members...

Comment: @Jarod42 It is. From what I understand it's still fairly commonly used.

Comment: I can't seem to find a good reason to insist on assignment. what's wrong with `const T& x() const` and `void setX(T t)`?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jarod’s comment regarding the usability/“ugliness” of using function calls. But just to show (also to myself) that this is possible, you can mock “call-less” getters using implicit conversion operators.

Now whether this is a “good idea” is a very different question:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t I>
struct named_subset {
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    T* p;

    static_assert(I < N, "invalid index");

    named_subset(T* p) : p{p} {}

    operator value_type() { return (*p)[I]; }

    named_subset& operator =(value_type const& rhs) {
        (*p)[I] = rhs;
        return *this;
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct vec_n {
    using value_type = T;
    T values[N];
    named_subset<vec_n, N, 0> x{this};
    named_subset<vec_n, N, 1> y{this};
    named_subset<vec_n, N, 2> z{this};
    named_subset<vec_n, N, 3> w{this};

    T& operator [](std::size_t i) { return values[i]; }
};
```

(The interface in the above is simplified, and notably omits `const` overloads.)

Of course this blows up the size of your struct, because each getter needs to carry around with it a pointer to its owner. I don’t think there’s a way around that.

Comment: This is technically "without references" but qualitatively nearly the same thing as the reference technique in the question.

Comment: @aschepler The crucial difference is the `static_assert`, which makes it *safe*. I agree that all other drawbacks apply, and wouldn’t recommend this technique.

Comment: it sure is ugly and cryptographic, I appreciate the effort though.